# Source of Ramayan and Mahabharath which were written originally

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, ramayana, resource

I read almost all the stories of Ramayana and Mahabharata.
But my question is:

- At present where are the original Ramayana and Mahabharata manuscripts which were written by  Valmiki and Vyasa Maharshi?
- Do they still exist or are they decomposed?

Comment: Vyasa didn't write a manuscript himself, he dictated the Mahabharata to Ganesha who wrote it down.  But that manuscript is long lost, and the Mahabharata wasn't passed down by manuscripts anyway, it was passed down by oral tradition.  And in the case of the Ramayana, it was never committed to writing by Valmiki, it was passed down by oral tradition from the start.

Comment: You can read [Interpolations In The Mahabharata](https://archive.org/details/InterpolationsInTheMahabharata) by Prof. M. A. Mehendale of [BORI](http://www.bori.ac.in/mahabharata_project.html) and also [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16245/2995). It's impossible to find unaltered, original Ramayana and Mahabharata manuscripts.