# How many puranas got interpolation?

Tags: puranas, interpolation

Do bhagavatam got interpolation
Do Shiva purana got interpolation
Do Devi bhagavatam got interpolation
Do Vishnu Purana
Do 18 puranas got interpolation

Comment: Interpolations are not easy to decide. They are opinion based questions.

Comment: Even if there are interpolations how to find them? Its not possible. I have asked a question about this already (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16234/what-are-the-valid-and-foolproof-methods-of-determining-whether-a-certain-script). No one came up with a convincing answer yet.

Comment: All are interpolated.

Comment: The bhagavatan is also interpolated

Comment: Yes the Bhagavatam also (Devi mahapuran and Srimad both)

Comment: On this what. You are informating