# Were hindu scriptures changed by outsiders to foster conversion?

Tags: puranas, manu-smriti

Many people pull of changed in the puranas or manusmriti do degrade hinduism,but this isn't true.

Hindu scripture was changed,but can any one give me proof that this was done?

Har har mahadev.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16234/26679

Comment: Unfortunately not,I wanted historical proof proving that mughals and British changed hindu scriptures